# Changing the underlying HTML of an asp:DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need to dramatically change the underlying HTML of an existing DetailsView control, far beyond what is available in the properties of the TemplateField control.

For instance, there are specific sizes of gaps between fields that are implemented as rows and columns in the structural table. The 'required' marker is a table cell that has a background color. Things like that.

Isn't there a way to provide a whole new template to the DetailsView control?

Ninja Edit:

Per request, here is the totally obtuse requirement for the DetailsView formatting.

```
  <tr>
      <td>
          <table class="question_spacer io_table" width="100%">
              <tbody>
                  <tr class="io_label " id="blah">
                      <td colspan="2" oncontextmenu="some JavaScript;">
                        <span style="margin-left: 1px;" id="blah" class="changed" title="Mandatory - must be populated before Submit" oclass="mandatory">&nbsp;</span>
                        <label for="Blah">What is your full name?</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td width="100%">
                        <input value="blah" class="cat_item_option" type="hidden" id="blah" onchange="someJavaScript" name="blah">
                        <input type="hidden" onchange="Javascripthere" value="sys_user" id="blah" name="blah">
                        <input value="" type="hidden" id="blah">
                        <input title="" value="" class="questionsetreference" onkeyup="js" onkeydown="js" onkeypress="js" ac_order_by="name" ac_columns="user_name" id="blah" name="blah" onfocus="js">
                        <a tabindex="1" style="padding-right:4px;" id="blah" onclick="js">
                          <img title="Lookup using list" height="16" src="images/reference" border="0" width="18">
                        </a>
                        <span style="" id="name">
                          <a tabindex="1" id="catalog_super_diamond_anchor" onmouseout="js" onclick="js" onmousemove="js">
                            <img height="16" style="align: left; display: " width="16" src="images/icons/hover_icon.gifx" border="0" id="blah" name="blah">
                          </a>
                          <img height="16" style="align: left; display: none;" width="16" tabindex="1" src="images/s.gifx" border="0" id="blah" name="view.sys_user.no">
                        </span>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Are you able to give a very specific example of something you are unable to do?  Little confused as to what exactly you can't do but maybe I am just not understanding your scenario so a simple description of a change you want might make it a bit clearer so I can help.

Comment: Edited per your request. Supposedly integrating it with a boxed product apparently written by an architecture astronaut.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping for a 'simple' example.  Is that example the HTML you want as output?  Your example has confused me even more lol.  Where does the `DetailView` fit in there or does it produce that?

If you want that produced by the `DetailView` then you will obviously need to use `TemplateField` and then implement the `OnDataBinding` of the controls within the `TemplateField` to get the customizing you require which you can manipulate at the control level to do almost anything...

What is the part that you can't get working using the `TemplateField`?

Comment: That is what ONE TemplateField looks like in the DetailView. How bout DEM apples?  I will have to look at the TemplateField more closely - it seemed to 'automagically' add (for instance) the label with the field name. Clearly am going to have to change the HTML surrounding that. I'll look at OnDataBinding and see if it is more obvious then.